# DataStax Enterprise with HDFS and Spark without Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hdfs, datastax-enterprise

Is it possible to work with DSE, HDFS, Spark, but without Cassandra?

I try to replace CFS (Cassandra File System) with HDFS (Hadoop in DSE)

```
dse hadoop fs -help
```

needs cassandra.

Cassandra takes a lot of memory, I hope that with HDFS-only we've get more free-RAM on node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling DSE Hadoop is actually using the Cassandra file system instead of HDFS so you cannot run it without Cassandra running. Datastax does support a BYOH (bring your own Hadoop) option but that involves using a third party Hadoop. If you don't want Cassandra though I would not recommend using the DSE packaging.